# How to find the Inverse of a Matrix in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, matrix

I have a Matrix with several rows/columns. The number of columns is always equal to the number of rows but I don't know the exact number since they are the result of another query.

Here is a simple example with 2 columns/rows

```
      ID1  ID2
1     4    7
2     2    6
```

I get this Matrix from a table that looks like this:

```
ID1 ID2 Value
1   1   4
1   2   7
2   1   2
2   2   6
```

Now I would like to have the Inverse of that Matrix.

The result would look like this in a Matrix:

```
    ID1    ID2
1   0.6    -0.7
2   -0.2   0.4
```

Or like this in a table:

```
ID1 ID2 Value
1   1   0.6
1   2   -0.7
2   1   -0.2
2   2   0.4
```

It is basically the Excel Formula ={MINVERSE(Array)} in SQL Server

In my Database I have both, Table and Matrix so I can use what would work best to find its inverse.

Comment: I think doing this in SQL is a bad idea. Storing it in a database seems reasonable with the schema you have, but trying to manipulate it in an RDBMS... it's a stretch since you are taking into account relationships as defined within the data itself. It seems more proper to do this outside of the database in a program designed to deal with matrix data.

Comment: @JNevill What do you think you be the proper software to handle large Matrix like that (200X200)? The work I do with this is basically financial engineering, risk-return  calculation.

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't often work with matrix data. I would imagine a language that is more geared towards analysis and statistics like R would be a good starting point though. [This tutorial](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/matrix) seems to suggest that R would be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation for a 2x2 matrix. It's ugly because a matrix is not relationship in the sense that a RDBMS is relational. But perhaps it will get you close enough.

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN id1=id2 THEN CASE WHEN id1=1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END ELSE ID1 END as ID2,
   CASE WHEN id1=id2 THEN CASE WHEN id2=1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END ELSE ID2 END as ID2,
   CASE WHEN id1<>id2 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * matrix.value/(determinate1.value-determinate2.value) as inverse_value
FROM
  (SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(value))) as value FRom matrix where id1=id2) as determinate1,
  (SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(value))) as value FROM matrix WHERE id1<>id2) as determinate2,
  matrix;
```

Here it is in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66208/8)